Equation of how to flip a polygon 180 degrees, and place nested inside parent polygon?
I am trying to position and scale this black pentagram inside the gray one perfectly, but haven't figured out the right equation.

There are two parts to solving this:

How do you determine the inner radius of the parent polygon (assuming polygon can be from 3 to 20 sides)?
Given that radius, how do you calculate the positional offset (x and y offset) of the child black polygon, so it fits perfectly touching the edges of the parent polygon?

I used these but they seem to be giving incorrect results:
shortestAltitudeOfPolygon = parentRadius * (2 * Math.sin(Math.PI / sides))
childRadius = parentRadius * Math.cos(Math.PI / sides)

The x and y offset to position it properly, I simply have been manually adjusting it until it looks about right, with a transform(16, 22) sort of approach (in code). How can I calculate that more accurately?

I agree with your childRadius.  For shortestAltitudeOfPolygon, you have calculated the length of its side.  The length I think of the shortest altitude is $R(1+\cos(\pi/N))$ if $N$ is odd and $R(2\cos(\pi/N))$ if $N$ is even
